# Google play services is crashing my Samsung J7 phone

Tags: samsung, google-play-services, device-administrator

Google services is crashing my Samsung J7 phone.

I can't disable or force stop the app. The button is inaccessible.

I can't uninstall updates: it tells me "administrator protected",  I need to give permission.

I went to device administrator. When I click on the box (find my device) to disable it, now settings stop working and I go back to my screen.

I tried:

- to switch the phone on off
- wifi on-off
- airplane mode
- force stop all google apps
- disable from safe mode
- disable from settings (through lock screen and security)
- also all google apps are crashing too
- google chrome, google search, playstore

I still get the " google play services keeps stopping" message.

Comment: Disable Wifi and cellular data, clean the app data of google services and reboot the device. Does the service still crash? If not re-enable Wifi and leave the phone alone for some hours (hopefully this will update data and/or app of play services to a stable version).

Comment: i cannot press clean app data.  norforcestop or disable.